# tableview section displaying two cell but number of rows for that section is 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, swift

I had a tableview with three section. I am using two custom cells (one for first and last section and one for the middle section). The issue is that when the tableview is reloaded after initial loading it gets into the section zero two times even if the no of rows in section 0 is set as 1. Here is the code:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        var noOfRows = 0
        switch(section){
        case 0:
//            if arraySearchResultODXTop.count > 0{
                noOfRows = 1
//            }
        case 1:
            if(array_SearchResults.count > 0){
                noOfRows = array_SearchResults.count
            }
        case 2:
            noOfRows = 1
        default:
            return 0
        }

        return noOfRows
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        var cellIdentifier:String?
        switch (indexPath.section){
        case 0, 2:
            cellIdentifier = "cell1"
        case 1:
            cellIdentifier = "cell"
        default:
            cellIdentifier = "cell"
        }
        var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier!,forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell
        var apartment:AFApartmentListing?

        switch (indexPath.section){

        case 0:

            if (indexPath.row == 0){
                println("section and row...\(indexPath.section),\(indexPath.row)")
                if self.arraySearchResultODXTop.count > 0{
                    apartment = self.arraySearchResultODXTop[1] as? AFApartmentListing
                }
                var topCell:AFODXView? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier!, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? AFODXView
                if (topCell == nil){
                    topCell = AFODXView(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
                }
                topCell!.setupCell(apartment)
                cell = topCell! as AFODXView
                break
        }


        case 1:
           var cell:AFSearchResultsTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier!, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? AFSearchResultsTableViewCell
           if (cell == nil){
                cell = AFSearchResultsTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
           }
            apartment = array_SearchResults[indexPath.row] as? AFApartmentListing
            cell!.delegate = self
            cell!.setupCellWithApartment(apartment!)
            cell = cell! as AFSearchResultsTableViewCell
            break

        case 2:
            if (indexPath.row == 0){
                println("last section...\(indexPath.section),\(indexPath.row)")
                if self.arraySearchResultODXBottom.count > 0{
                    apartment = self.arraySearchResultODXBottom[0] as? AFApartmentListing
                }
                    var bottomCell:AFODXView?
                    bottomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier!, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? AFODXView
                if (bottomCell == nil){
                    bottomCell = AFODXView(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
                }

                bottomCell!.setupCell(apartment)
                cell = bottomCell! as AFODXView
                break

            }

        default:
            cell = nil
            return cell!
        }
        return cell!
    }
```

Comment: in switch statement you should use break operation: case: 0 {..} break; case 1: {} break; ...

Comment: @stosha that is not the problem i think. In swift once it get into a case it automatically jumps out of switch, anyway i checked giving break statements manually too, but it did't work. Any help plz..

Comment: @stosha Not in Swift.